# SQL : match updates from one table to another based on columns

Tags: sql

What is the difference between the two writing methods
[two difference sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLQ3z.png)

Is it different because of different databases?

Comment: It is advised not to use images

Comment: "Is it different because of different databases?" -> Difficult to answer if you are not interested in telling us which different databases you use.